# Dropdown Based on Vlookup Match

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, vlookup

I'm looking for a Dropdown that uses a `Vlookup` to pull specific content:

Here's the scenario:

Table

```
    A    |   B
Category | Item
Fruit    | Apple
Fruit    | Orange
Veg      | Potato
Fruit    | Guava 
Fruit    | Tomato 
Veg      | Lettuce 
Fruit    | Pear 
Veg      | Cucumber 
Veg      | Spinach
```

What I'm looking for is the following:

I have (for example) 2 Dropdowns.

Dropdown 1 (Only a list of Fruit. )

```
Apple 
Orange 
Guava  
Tomato 
Pear
```

Dropdown 2 (Only a list of Veg.)

```
Potato 
Lettuce 
Cucumber 
Spinach
```

The table will have more than 2 columns, but the basics will get me started.

Answer (score 0):

You may be headed in the wrong direction. In a new blank worksheet, put this table into AA1:AB6.

[image: Fruit Vegetable drop downs]

1. Select B3 and choose Data ► Data Validation. Select Allow: List and Source: =$AA$1:$AB$1
    
           [image: Fruit Vegetable drop downs]
2. Select B5 and choose Data ► Data Validation. Select Allow: List and Source: =INDEX($AA$2:$AB$6, , MATCH($B$3, $AA$1:$AB$1, 0))
    
           [image: Fruit Vegetable drop downs]
    
           [image: Fruit Vegetable drop downs]

Selecting one of the column header labels will match the [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) and supply the correct sub-list to the second dropdown.

More columns with column header labels can be added. Just adjust the ranges on the Data Validation list sources.

Comment: Thank you... Note quite what I want... Let's assume that there are 100 different Categories. I don't want to create 100 tables. This also needs to be dynamic as there may be unknown (new) categories.

Comment: If you had a new category for Shoes then you would put Shoes in AC1 and Sneakers, Loafers, Slippers, Sandals in AC2:AC5. The formulas I have given you can be made to automatically adjust to new column being added. Search for *dynamic named range*.

Comment: But creating a new Table each time will require constant Development and is not dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Put your list of fruit in a named range called "Fruit" and your list of veg in a named range called "Veg".

Assuming your category is in column A and you want the drop-down in column B, then click in cell *B2* and on the *DATA* tab on the ribbon, select *Data Validation*.

Select *Data Validation* from the drop-down and change the top drop-down box to *List*.

In the *Source* box at the bottom enter:

```
=INDIRECT(A2)
```

Select OK and copy down the column.

**EDIT: Cater for an unknown number of different categories**

You can adapt the approach proposed by @Jeeped by including a set of tables that populate themselves dynamically as shown here:

The ARRAY formula for the column headers (in cells E1:M1) is:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$100, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($C$1:D1, $A$2:$A$100), 0)),"")}
```

and the ARRAY formula for the rows beneath the headers is:

```
{=INDEX($B:$B,SMALL(IF($A:$A=E$1,ROW($A:$A)-MIN(ROW($A:$A))+1),ROWS($A$1:$A1)))}
```

[image]

I must warn you, however, that the performance of the workbook will be poor because the array formulae are having to do a lot of work.

Comment: Thank you... Note quite what I want... Let's assume that there are 100 different Categories. I don't want to create 100 tables. This also needs to be dynamic as there may be unknown (new) categories.

Comment: Ok, if all your combinations of category and Item are in a single table, I would need to understand a bit more about your exact requirements to determine the best approach. Where is the drop-down list going to appear? Is there just one on the sheet, or are you expecting an in-cell drop-down to be available against every row in some other table? If the former, it can be achieved with formulae or possibly by using pivot tables / slicers. If you need the latter, then you are likely to need VBA code.